# How to write a regex capture group which matches a character 3 or 4 times before a delimiter?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regex that splits elements out according to a delimiter.  The regex also needs to ensure there are ideally 4, but at least 3 colons `:` in each match.

Here's an example string:

```
"Checkers, etc:Blue::C, Backgammon, I say:Green::Pepsi:P, Chess, misc:White:Coke:Florida:A, :::U"
```

From this, there should be 4 matches:

- `Checkers, etc:Blue::C`
- `Backgammon, I say:Green::Pepsi:P`
- `Chess, misc:White:Coke:Florida:A`
- `:::U`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
([^:]*:[^:]*){3,4}(?:, )
```

Regex 101 at: https://regex101.com/r/O8iacP/8

I tried setting up a non-capturing group for `,`

Then I tried matching a group of any character that's not a `:`, a `:`, and any character that's not a `:` 3 or 4 times.

The code I'm using to iterate over these groups is:

```
String line = "Checkers, etc:Blue::C, Backgammon, I say::Pepsi:P, Chess:White:Coke:Florida:A, :::U";
String pattern = "([^:]*:[^:]*){3,4}(?:, )";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher matcher = r.matcher(line);
  while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**

Using @Casimir's regex, it's working.  I had to change the above code to use group(0) like this:

```
String line = "Checkers, etc:Blue::C, Backgammon, I say::Pepsi:P, Chess:White:Coke:Florida:A, :::U";
String pattern = "(?![\\s,])(?:[^:]*:){3}\\S*(?![^,])";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher matcher = r.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Now prints:

```
Checkers, etc:Blue::C
Backgammon, I say::Pepsi:P
Chess:White:Coke:Florida:A
:::U
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this pattern:

```
(?![\\s,])(?:[^:]*:){3}\\S*(?![^,])
```

Negative lookaheads avoid to match leading or trailing delimiters. The second one in particular forces the match to be followed by the delimiter or the end of the string (*not followed by a character that isn't a comma*).

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtvARf/1)

Note that the pattern doesn't have capture groups, so the result is the whole match (or group 0).

Comment: I appreciate this.  I'm going to work to add this to my code without the matching groups.  It definitely looks like it's working.

Comment: As you said, this doesn't use any matching groups.  For the Java code given in the original post... how does one get the individual captures?  The `matcher.find()` returns `false` now

Comment: @Cuga: like that: `System.out.println(matcher.group(0));`

Comment: I updated the post at the bottom to show what I mean.  `matcher.find()` returns false and `matcher.group(0)` gives an IllegalStateException

Comment: @Cuga: but why did you suppress the `while` loop?

Comment: It's never entering because `matcher.find()` returns false...

Comment: Ok, I have it working now.  Thanks a million!  I'd never have gotten this

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
(?:[^,:]+, )?[^:,]*(?::+[^:,]+)+
```

- `(?:[^,:]+, )?` Optionally match 1+ any char except a `,` or `:` followed by `,` and space
- `[^:,]*` Match 0+ any char except `:` or `,`
- `(?:` Non Capturing group

  - `:+[^:,]+` Match 1+ `:` and 1+ times any char except `:` and `,`
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Is7Zqd/1)

Comment: Man, I appreciate it.  One thing tho- this regex is matching the trailing space after the comma delimiter.  In this case, my actual delimiter is 2 chars-- a comma and space.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be making it harder than it needs to be with the lookahead (which won't be satisfied at end-of-line anyway).

```
([^:]*:){3}[^:,]*:?[^:,]*
```

Find the first 3 `:`'s, then start including `,` in the negative groupings, with an optional 4th `:`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff Y.  This is missing the last element though... :::U